# console.log/console.dir showing last state of object, not current

Tags: javascript, logging, console.log

I want to log how my array/object is changing with new steps of loop. `Console.log` does this bad. It shows only last state of object everywhere. For example:

```
var a = {};
console.log(a); // {bob1: 0, bob2: 0}
a.bob1 = 0;
console.log(a); // {bob1: 0, bob2: 0}
a.bob2 = 0;
console.log(a); // {bob1: 0, bob2: 0}
```

I found there, on so, another command: `console.dir`. It is working properly in same example. It shows states of object correcly.

Look this example. This command works perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/RLzVV/

Now, look my code pls. All output is in console. http://jsfiddle.net/3BDs7/4/

This is aStar algorithm. Take a look on this part (neighbor 3 loop `<--- neighbor 3 start ---> this code is situated here <--- neighbor 3 stop -->`) in console. Lanes, which output this to console are `105-113`:

```
new openset length: 2
openset after adding new vertex
**shows 1 element, but length is 2**
```

It shows length is 2, but shows only 1 element. But! Seems to me algo is working correctly (it is popping another element, which is hidden on this step after). Why this bug appears? Did I did something wrong? Seems to me, everywhere only last state of array shown, not current:( help me please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a known issue -- sounds like you are running under Chrome.

The easiest work-around is to JSON encode the value as you log in.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```